# Running react app in browser issues with saving and editing

Tags: reactjs

When I run my react app in the browser, everything works fine. But when I edit a file and it gets saved, I can still see the whole app but when I try to interact with it, it doesnt work, I did inspect element and saw that the body that does not contain anything. Yet the content is visible?
Any solutions?

---

Note , when I reload the page everything is working fine, but its annoying to have to reload the page everytime.

Comment: try to rerun the dev server

Answer (score 1):

Next JS is based on Reactjs and this might be helpful for you:

**[Limitations](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#limitations)**

> Fast Refresh tries to preserve local React state in the component
> you're editing, but only if it's safe to do so. Here's a few reasons
> why you might see local state being reset on every edit to a file:
>
> Local state is not preserved for class components (only function components and Hooks preserve state).
> The file you're editing might have other exports in addition to a React component.
> Sometimes, a file would export the result of calling a higher-order component like HOC(WrappedComponent). If the returned
> component is a class, its state will be reset.
> Anonymous arrow functions like export default () => ; cause Fast Refresh to not preserve local component state. For large
> codebases you can use our name-default-component codemod.
>
> As more of your codebase moves to function components and Hooks, you
> can expect state to be preserved in more cases.

You can read more about [FastRefresh](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh) from the documentation.